# Migration from ExtJS 3.0 to 4.0

Tags: javascript, extjs

Previously in ext 3.0 we had Tree Panel built from XML response.
For that we had custom class extending 'Ext.tree.TreeLoader'
This TreeLoader was useful to build tree structure (parent/child nodes).

While migrating to 4.0 found that TreeLoader class is missing.
Is there any replacement to this class or any other way to build tree structure?

I want to generate tree structure for following xml :
Actually, I want to build tree structure from this XML :

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<Root>
<Folder>
<CreateDate>Apr 29, 2011</CreateDate>
<CreatedBy>1000</CreatedBy>
<Files/>
<FolderName>Testing</FolderName>
<FolderNamePath/>
<FolderPath/>
<Folders>
<Folder>
<CreateDate>Apr 6, 2011</CreateDate>
<CreatedBy>1000</CreatedBy>
<Files/>
<FolderName>JayM</FolderName>
<Folders>
<Folder>
<CreateDate>Apr 6, 2011</CreateDate>
<CreatedBy>1000</CreatedBy>
<Files/>
<FolderName>JaM</FolderName>
<Id>2000</Id>
<ModDate>Dec 30, 2011</ModDate>
<ParentFolderId>1948</ParentFolderId>
</Folder>
</Folders>
<Id>1948</Id>
<ModBy>1000</ModBy>
<ModDate>Dec 30, 2011</ModDate>
<ParentFolderId>1</ParentFolderId>
</Folder>

<Folder>
<CreateDate>Dec 2, 2011</CreateDate>
<CreatedBy>1000</CreatedBy>
<Files/>
<FolderName>demo folder</FolderName>
<Folders/>
<Id>2427</Id>
<ModBy/>
<ModDate/>
<ParentFolderId>1</ParentFolderId>
</Folder>

</Folders>
<Id>1</Id>
<ModBy/>
<ModDate/>
<ParentFolderId/>
</Folder>
</Root>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to look into the [TreeStore](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.TreeStore) which, along with any standard Proxy (plus XmlReader in your case), replaced TreeLoader in Ext 4. TreeStore contains standard Model instances (i.e., records) that have been decorated by the [NodeInterface](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.NodeInterface) class to provide tree-specific behavior. The API is now very similar to the standard store / record API, unlike TreeLoader in 3.x which was completely separate.

Have a look at the [tree examples](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/#sample-6), specifically the [XML tree example](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/tree/xml-tree.html) in your case, for usage.

Comment: Thanks bmoeskau! can you give any TreeStore example other than Sencha Docs?

Comment: Please see the example links above

Answer (score 1):

In ExtJS 4, you have tree panel instead of tree loader to build tree structure(parent/child nodes).

**Example Code:**

```
var treepanel = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel',{ 
id : 'tree', 
width : 300, 
height : 300, 
store : testStore, 
rootVisible : false 
});
```

Comment: Tree panel exists in both Ext 3 and 4 and has nothing to do with loading data. The loading changed from TreeLoader to TreeStore + proxy.